# error occored when make project for ros java

Tags: rosmake, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hanbo@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/my_package$ rosmake my_package
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['my_package']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/hanbo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120314-055706
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['my_package'] to:
['my_package']
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages my_package.  This may take a few seconds.
Failed to find stack for package [rosgraph_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [rosgraph_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package rosgraph_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [rosgraph_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/hanbo/ros_workspace]
Failed to find stack for package [sensor_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [sensor_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package sensor_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [sensor_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/hanbo/ros_workspace]
Failed to find stack for package [std_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [std_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package std_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [std_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/hanbo/ros_workspace]
Failed to find stack for package [rostest]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [rostest]:Cannot locate installation of package rostest: [rospack] couldn't find package [rostest]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/hanbo/ros_workspace]
Failed to find stack for package [test_ros]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [test_ros]:Cannot locate installation of package test_ros: [rospack] couldn't find package [test_ros]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/hanbo/ros_workspace]
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> my_package [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< my_package [SKIP] No rule to make target None
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 0 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/hanbo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120314-055706

- List item

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29669/error-occored-when-make-project-for-ros-java/) by [hanbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1967/hanbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not set up correctly. Also, rosjava does not support rosmake. See http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0